# find the range $(x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{2009})^2=4(x_{1}x_{2}+x_{2}x_{3}+\cdots+x_{2009}x_{1})^2$

Tags: inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

let $x_{i}\ge 0(i=1,2,3,\cdots,2009$,and such $$(x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{2009})^2=4(x_{1}x_{2}+x_{2}x_{3}+\cdots+x_{2009}x_{1})=4$$
find the range  $\sum_{i=1}^{2009}x^2_{i}$

I guess the range is $[1.5,2]$ 
because I think when $x_{1}=1,x_{2}=1,x_{3}=x_{4}=\cdots=x_{2009}=0$then is maximum of value $2$

and when $x_{1}=0.5,x_{2}=1,x_{3}=0.5,x_{4}=\cdots=x_{2009}=0$ is minmum of the value  $1.5$

Comment: The title and the question don't match. *Equal to four* is missing from the title, and the sum of mixed products is squared in the title but not in the body. Fix it, please. Not that it matters much :-)

Comment: Is this from some old contest by any chance? Adding such details gives some context to the question, and helps answerers in gauging what tools you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are right!

We'll prove that
$$(x_1+x_2+...+x_{2009})^2\geq4(x_1x_2+x_2x_3+...+x_{2009}x_1)$$ for all non-negatives $x_i$.

Indeed, let $x_2=\max\limits_{i}\{x_i\}$.

Thus, $$x_2x_{2009}\geq x_1x_{2009}$$ and by AM-GM we obtain:
$$4(x_1x_2+x_2x_3+...+x_{2009}x_1)\leq4(x_1+x_3+...+x_{2009})(x_2+x_4+...+x_{2008})\leq\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2009}x_i\right)^2,$$
where the equality occurs for
$$x_1(x_4+x_6+...+x_{2008})=0,$$ 
$$x_2(x_5+...+x_{2007})=0,$$ which gives
$$x_5=...=x_{2007}=0.$$ 
Now, if $x_1=0$ then $x_2x_3=1,$ which gives 
$$2=\sum_{i=1}^{2009}x_i\geq x_2+x_{3}\geq2\sqrt{x_2x_{3}}=2,$$
which gives $x_2=x_{3}=1$, $x_1=x_4=...=x_{2009}=0$ and  $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2009}x_i^2=2$.

If $x_1>0$ we obtain:
$$x_1(x_4+...+x_{2008})=0,$$ 
which gives $x_4=x_5=...=x_{2008}=0.$

Now, let $x_2=a$, $x_1=b$,$x_3=c$ and $x_{2009}=d$.

Thus, $$(a+b+c+d)^2=4(ab+bd+ca)=4,$$
which gives $a+b+c+d=2$ and $ab+bd+ca=1.$

Thus,  by AM-GM  $$1=ab+bd+ca=ab+bd+dc+ca-dc=(a+d)(b+c)-dc\leq$$
$$\leq\left(\frac{a+b+c+d}{2}\right)^2-dc=1-dc\leq1,$$
which gives $dc=0$ and $a+d=b+c=1.$

Now, let $c=0$.

Thus, $b=1=a+d$ and since $a\geq b$, we obtain $d=0$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2009}x_i^2=2$ again.

Let $d=0$.

Id est, by C-S 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2009}x_i^2=a^2+b^2+c^2=1+\frac{1}{2}(1+1)(b^2+c^2)\geq1+\frac{1}{2}(b+c)^2=1.5.$$
The equality occurs for $a=1$ and $b=c=\frac{1}{2},$ which says that we got a minimal value.

Also, $$\sum_{i=1}^{2009}x_i^2=a^2+b^2+c^2=1+(b+c)^2-2bc\leq1+(b+c)^2=2.$$
The equality occurs for $a=b=1$ and $c=0,$ which says that we got a maximal value.

Comment: Good job! Getting the maximum was, of course, easy (estimate the second symmetric polynomial). But the minimum was too difficult for me :-)  I developed a suspicion that we can never have more than three non-zero entries, but couldn't prove it.

Comment: $x_{1}=\max?$,so  LHS can't less than RHS

Comment: @communnites About which LHS and RHS do you say?

Comment: I think $x_{2}=\max$,because if $x_{1}=\max$ then  why$$4(x_{1}x_{2}+\cdots+x_{2009}x_{1})\le 4(x_{1}+x_{3}+\cdots+x_{2009})(x_{2}+x_{4}+\cdots+x_{2008})$$? and if $x_{2}$ it is right,I think $x_{1}$ is max not hold

Comment: @communnites See it again. It's obvious! It's like $x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_4+x_4x_5+x_5x_1\leq(x_1+x_3+x_5)(x_2+x_4),$ where $x_2\leq x_1$.

Comment: Just open brackets!

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg Consider the tems containg $x_5$. LHS is $\cdots+x_4x_5+x_5x_1$, and $RHS$ is $\cdots+x_2x_5+x_4x_5.$. But $x_5x_1 \leq x_2x_5$?

Comment: Moreover，I think we can not assume that $a_1=\max\left\{a_i\right\}$ here, since the situation is not symmetric.

Comment: Yes, I see. It should be $x_2=\max\{x_i\}$. I'll fix it. Thank you! But the idea is the same.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg But I think you can not  assume that $a_2=\max{ai}$,  since the situation is not symmetric.

Comment: I can. Because the inequality is cyclic. @communnites I fixed. See now.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg,Thanks,Now I have understand

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

We are to state a lemma, on which the whole thing is based.

> #### Lemma
>
> Let $n > 4$ and $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1}$ be non-negative real
>   numbers, with $x_0=x_n$ and $x_{n+1} = x_1$. Then $$\left (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right )^2 \geq 4\sum_{i=1}^n
> x_{i}x_{i+1},$$
>   with the equality holding if and only if, for any $j~~ (1\leq j\leq n)$ we have$$x_j =\dfrac {1}{2} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i = x_{j-1}+x_{j+1}$$ and the rest
>   of the variables are equal to $0$.

Come back to the present case. Since $n=2009> 4$,  $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i = 2$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_{i}x_{i+1} = 1$, thus the equality holds. Therefore, for any $j~~~(1 \leq j \leq 2009)$, we have $x_j=1$,$x_{j-1}+x_{j+1}=1,$ and the rest are equal to $0$.

Under these constraints, we obtain $$S = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 = x_j^2 + x_{j-1}^2 + x_{j+1}^2 =1 + x_{j-1}^2 + x_{j+1}^2,$$ where $x_{j-1}, x_{j+1} \geq 0$ and $x_{j-1}+x_{j+1}= 1$. Thus, $\dfrac {1}{2} \leq x_{j-1}^2 + x_{j+1}^2 \leq 1$, therefore $$\dfrac {3}{2} \leq S \leq 2.$$

Comment: How to get the only and only if?